# How to append output to an empty list without index, name and dtype?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I am trying to append output to an empty list, but it also appends index, name, and dtype.
This is the code:

```
China_pop=[]
for year in range(1,101,1):
    x=(df[df.country=="China"]["population"]*((1+float(df[df.country=="China"]["yearly_change"].str.replace("%","",regex=True))/100))**year)
    China_pop.append(x)
China_pop
```

and this is the output:

[image]

I want to create a dataframe using this column, which ends up like this:
[image]

How can I append the output only? Is there a better way of creating this dataframe?

Comment: Can you please provide some programable data? We cannot copy paste a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Pandas will return a series most of the time when there's a single matching record and this is what you are getting here; the full series rather than 'pure' data.

2 possible solutions:

1. Instead of appending results to a list *then* creating a dataframe (from a list of series) you could simple change `China_Pop = []` to `China_Pop = pd.DataFrame()` which will allow you to append series to a dataframe.
   Issue with this solution is that it can be *slow* when you have lots of records.
2. You could convert each series into a dict/json with .to_dict()/.to_json() and append those results to the list. This should then load into a dataframe properly.

A final though, that's untested but might work and if it does would probably be your best/fastest solution is to add .values to your x variable (the one you append to the list)